# Error while converting Bitmaps to AVI using Accord.Video.VFW.dll

Tags: bitmap, avi, accord.net

While converting Bitmaps to AVi with Accord.Video.VFW.dll, i use this code:

```
AVIWriter writer = new AVIWriter();
// create new AVI file and open it
writer.Open( "test.avi", 320, 240 );
// create frame image
Bitmap image = new Bitmap( 320, 240 );

for ( int i = 0; i < 240; i++ )
{
    // update image
    image.SetPixel( i, i, Color.Red );
    // add the image as a new frame of video file
    writer.AddFrame( image );
}
writer.Close( );
```

In line

```
writer.AddFrame( image );
```

Always getting error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.OverflowException' in Accord.Video.VFW.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "preferably 32 bit" in the build menu in the project properties
[image]